# How to create OAuthClient Id in Goole API console for multiple projects

Tags: android, google-signin

I am working on an Android application, which support multiple countries like Germany, Switzerland, UK etc. For each project I have created a project in Google API console. I have generated OAuthClient Id  for my release and debug signing keys in one project.

When I am trying to generate OAuthClient Id  in another project i.e. UK, I am getting Duplicate Fingerprint error.

Is there any way to generate OAuthClient Id for same android application in multiple projects?

Answer (score 0):

NO. I think its not possible. You can create multiple Oauth client id in google api console single project.

Comment: You can create or you cannot?