# How to generate SHA1 fingerprint for OAuth client ID, for two different projects?

Tags: android, google-signin

I am trying to generate SHA1 fingerprint for OAuth client ID , its generating successfully but problem is that i am using same SHA1 fingerprint(in both project android studio generate same SHA1 fingerprint) for two different project with different package name .

see the image below !

[image]

Note : i found this link but never answered !

[SHA1 fingerprint already used by another OAuth2 client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567551/sha1-fingerprint-already-used-by-another-oauth2-client)

[How to create OAuthClient Id in Goole API console for multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564430/how-to-create-oauthclient-id-in-goole-api-console-for-multiple-projects)

Thank You !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally i am able to deploy two or more projects , so trick is that don't insert your `SHA1` code in any projects .

**Note:** I don't know what happen if i published `apk` on a`playstore`

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of SHA1 code for each project.

- Debug SHA1
- Release SHA1

Debug SHA1 is generated automatically from your android studio, it is vary PC to PC.
Android studio generated one debug key for all project, basically it identified your PC.

But Release SHA1 is unique. It identified your app according to your .jks (Key) file.
One package name one release SHA1. If you provide your release SHA1 key into google developer console you can't add this key into any other project. Google Save your SHA1 key with your package name.

So there is no chance to duplicate release SHA1 for multiple project.